# How to display OpenCart Product List by Product IDs

Tags: php, opencart

I am creating a custom category page for my store. Currently on the Page I have the default product list showing all the products in the category, like in the image below:

[image]

I was wondering if it were someway possible to, instead of displaying every product in the category if I could choose specific products to show up with PHP? Like a query or something where I can have the product Ids separated by a comma?

Kinda like `<?php query by product ids (24,153,2,51,765) { ?>`

I know the code above doesnt work (ofcourse), but just hope that shows what Im trying to accomplish. Thanks in advance!

Below is the Code that Displays the Products like in the image above:

```
  <?php if ($products) { ?>
  <div class="product-filter">

    <div class="limit"><b><?php echo $text_limit; ?></b>
      <select onchange="location = this.value;">
        <?php foreach ($limits as $limits) { ?>
        <?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sort"><b><?php echo $text_sort; ?></b>
      <select onchange="location = this.value;">
        <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
        <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-compare"><a href="<?php echo $compare; ?>" id="compare-total"><?php echo $text_compare; ?></a></div>
  <div class="product-list">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div>
      <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
      <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
      <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
      <div class="price">
        <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
        <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="price-old"><span>MSRP: <?php echo $product['price']; ?></span></div> <div class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
        <br />
        <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
      <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="cart">
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
      </div>
      <div class="free-shipping"></div>
      <div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>
      <div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
  <div class="content"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="right"><a href="<?php echo $continue; ?>" class="button"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I guess you don't want to hard code product id's in view? (this could be easiest solution:))

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but at this point I'm up for anything! lol :)

Comment: Well... if hard coding inside category.tpl is an option - make array of product ids you want to show. Check if $product['product_id'] exists in array, and show it, and that's it. :)

Comment: That definitely sounds like it should work! Lets say my product ids are 5, 126, 70, & 24... could you give an example as how I would use it with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard-coding product filtering: :)

Find this line in category.tpl: ~  line 69

```
<div class="product-list">
```

Put this bellow: here foreach loop starts... You just have to put additional condition there.

```
<?php  $ids=array(43,44,45); // array of product id's   ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { if(in_array($product['product_id'],$ids)) {  ?>
```

...... template code.......

And bellow, at the loop end should look like this:

```
 <?php } }?>
```

add one more '}', (if condition must be closed properly). Should be line ~119.

P.S. Since you want filtering in just one category, i guess, one condition more should be made (if category id == selected category -> filter products...)

P.S.2 - Not sure about your intentions and desired goal, but rather than using of this dirty hack, use open cart built-in features (enable/disable product in admin panel), or try (if your problem is too specific) to make custom model/controller methods...

Comment: @JCBiggar, np, btw, now i realized - why you just wouldn't DISABLE product in admin panel, if you don't want it to be showed (temporary)  on category page? You can easily ENABLE it later...:))) LOL!

Comment: @nevermind Why wrap the code to IF? You can always us continue. if (!in_array($product['product_id'], $ignoredProductIds)) continue;

Comment: This really is a bad solution. Instead of limiting the amount of results populated from database to just concrete IDs You are still populating all relevant products and looping over them to display then only three? Sometimes I am wondering whether people use their brains when answering here... Of course disabling the products in administration is the firsthand and easiest solution, the "hard-coded" would be to filter the products in the SQL query directly to limit only wanted products being populated to save the resources...

Comment: @shadyyx, yes you are right, i am not using my brain when answering here, i am using my stomach, most of the times. Bad joke(s) and 'sublime tutor tone' aside, i have mentioned that modifying of template/view is not great solution, and that simple/enable disable product in admin panel, will solve problem. Targeting and changing SQL query is harder and i am not sure that it is option, because it would affect the rest of categories too... :) However, i would delete my answer too. :)

Comment: It wasn't meant in offence and directly against you, sorry if that sounds like it was. But it would be really nice if You could point that in the answer directly, that this is a dirty solution and that better would be something else so that the user doesn't think he just learnt something beautiful and keep developing in that way :-)

Comment: I'm having a problem with the above answer. It is displaying all the products properly, yet I have to set my products limit to a high number in order to show my few products on the page.

Comment: Ok, this is not standard category template, right? You don't want standard templates changed - it is ok. You will have to find way to make custom controller, and model for this page (or to make additional method in product model (check existing models and try to modify it, to make new method/model).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I really do not understand hwy asking such question to be solved programaticaly, because when You have a custom category and want to display only some concrete products, then all that is needed is to *unlink* unwanted products from this category. That' all!

Comment: Well the products belong in this category. But on this particular page I am creating, we only want to show certain products to display? Do you have another solution that would work?

Comment: Yes, create a *sub-category* and link only the wanted products to it. Then this particular page will point to that *sub-category* and the problem should be solved.